# System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, configuration

I am encountering the following error when I debug my application.

System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Otherwise, if I don't debug it just shows no data. I am very new to ASP.net and not sure how to continue to debug this, any help appreciated. I have tried stepping through the code but have had no luck. The view and the data work in another project was only when I tried to import it to this project that I had trouble.

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<QsccDevAlphaDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<QSCC_QAContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("QA_Context")));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

DBContext

```
namespace QsccDevAlpha.Data;

public partial class QSCC_QAContext : DbContext
{
    public QSCC_QAContext()
    {
    }

    public QSCC_QAContext(DbContextOptions<QSCC_QAContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AssetsByAssociate> AssetsByAssociate { get; set; }
```

controller.cs

```
 public class AssetsByAssociatesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly QSCC_QAContext _context;

        public AssetsByAssociatesController(QSCC_QAContext context)
        {

            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAssetsByAssociateData()
        {
            var data = _context.AssetsByAssociate.ToList();
            return Json(data);
        }
    }
```

appsetting.json

```
 
  "ConnectionStringQA": {
    "QA_Context": "Data Source=foo.bar.local;Initial Catalog=foo_qa;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetConnectionString` is basically an alias for `configuration?.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[name]`, so either move the `QA_Context` to `ConnectionStrings` section:

```json
"ConnectionStringQA": {
    "DefaultConnection": ....
    "QA_Context": "Data Source=foo.bar.local;Initial Catalog=foo_qa;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True"
  }
```

Or change the code to call appropriate method:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<QSCC_QAContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringQA")["QA_Context"]));
```

P.S.

It's a bit unusual approach to have multiple environments contexts at the same time.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Thank you. Create a public repo which matches your gh account name ([see more here](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme), add there readme.md and copy there flair embedding html.

Comment: @SunderamDubey was glad to help. P.S. comments are not the problem)

Comment: Ok sir I'd like to tell you one thing, currently I'm a teenager of 18, after 3 months I think from July, I'd be going to college for persuing bachelor's degree in computer science, so there I have to learn `C#`, so would you recommend me something to get good in it?

Comment: @SunderamDubey impressive rating for 18 y.o.! As for the books - will compile some list a bit later.

Comment: Ah thanks I hope you will remember me :) after making the list of books.

Comment: @SunderamDubey [here](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/c314bfcb86b71fec91ea6466c1c010c5). Though I can't recommend them as "newbies" books.